# Can not get text to rotate correctly

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-transforms

I am creating social media floating icons for my website, currently it is working fine, but i can not get the text the right way. Please help me figure this out and if you have any better ways of minimizing the code. 
Here is the build in Codepen.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
}

.share {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.share li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(1) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(1) .social-link:hover {
  background: #188ef4;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(1) .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s ease, -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s ease, -o-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #188ef4;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(1) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #188ef4;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(2) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(2) .social-link:hover {
  background: #db3236;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(2) .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s ease, -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s ease, -o-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #db3236;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(2) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #db3236;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(3) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(3) .social-link:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(3) .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s ease, -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s ease, -o-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #3B5998;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(3) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #3B5998;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(4) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(4) .social-link:hover {
  background: #c41200;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(4) .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s ease, -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s ease, -o-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #c41200;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(4) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #c41200;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(5) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(5) .social-link:hover {
  background: #ffc838;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(5) .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: background 0.4s ease, -moz-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background 0.4s ease, -o-transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.4s ease, -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #ffc838;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(5) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.1s;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #ffc838;
}

.share li .social-link {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.share li .social-link .nav-label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  top: 0rem;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 4;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s ease;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transform-origin: left 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: left 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left 50%;
  transform-origin: left 50%;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

.share li .social-link .nav-label span {
  -moz-transform-origin: left 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: left 50%;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left 50%;
  transform-origin: left 50%;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(270deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(270deg);
  transform: rotateY(270deg);
}

.share li .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.share li .social-link:hover .nav-label span {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Social Media Buildout</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Social Media testing">
  <meta name="author" content="Dev Patel">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="social-media.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>
  <ul class="share">
    <!--Facebook-->
    <li>
      <a href="request-an-appointment.html">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Request An Appointment</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--Google-->
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Review Us</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Like Our Page</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-yelp"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Review Us</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Check Our Posts</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct the CSS of `.share li .social-link .nav-label span` like this:

```
.share li .social-link .nav-label span {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Full code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: white;
}

.share {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.share li {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(1) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(1) .social-link:hover {
  background: #188ef4;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(1) .nav-label {
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #188ef4;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(1) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #188ef4;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(2) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(2) .social-link:hover {
  background: #db3236;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(2) .nav-label {
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #db3236;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(2) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #db3236;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(3) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(3) .social-link:hover {
  background: #3B5998;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(3) .nav-label {
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #3B5998;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(3) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #3B5998;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(4) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(4) .social-link:hover {
  background: #c41200;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(4) .nav-label {
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #c41200;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(4) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #c41200;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(5) .social-link,
.share li:nth-of-type(5) .social-link:hover {
  background: #ffc838;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(5) .nav-label {
  transition: background 0.4s ease, transform 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #ffc838;
}

.share li:nth-of-type(5) .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease, background 0.4s ease 0.1s;
  background: #ffc838;
}

.share li .social-link {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
}

.share li .social-link .nav-label {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  top: 0rem;
  line-height: 64px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 4;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  transform-origin: left 50%;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
}

.share li .social-link .nav-label span {
  transform-origin: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  display: inline-block;
}

.share li .social-link:hover .nav-label {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <ul class="share">
    <!--Facebook-->
    <li>
      <a href="request-an-appointment.html">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Request An Appointment</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--Google-->
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Review Us</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Like Our Page</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-yelp"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Review Us</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="social-link">
          <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
          <div class="nav-label">
            <span>Check Our Posts</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
```